# slack integration (OAuth vs Webhook)

Tags: oauth, slack-api

We are currently developing a Slack integration for pingon.me (web monitoring tool).

What would you prefer (as a user and/or as a developer):

1. Use OAuth and smoothly integrate Slack into pingon.me but not being
   listed on Slacks integration site
2. Force the user to fiddle around with the integration by using Slack Webhooks but being listed in Slacks integration site?

Or is there another option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use OAuth + Slack API and still be listed as an official integration — we'll work with you to make it official and get a pingon.me page added. Feel free to contact us at integrations@slack.com and we'll be in touch with the next steps shortly.

Comment: do we need to support for Oauth to list on integration page? Our tool(Atatus - Performance and Error monitoring) just need webhook url to send alert notification to Slack. But slack integration page always ask for redirect url(Oauth)?